# UITableViewDataSource implemented method not called

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create `UITableView` programmatically, but it makes me confuse because `UITableViewDataSource`'s protocol's implemented method never get called

**ViewController**

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
@end

#import "viewController.h"

@interface viewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tweetsArray;
@end

@implementation viewController {
    UITableView *tableView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tweetsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"This is the first line",
                        @"This is the second line",
                        @"This is the third line",
                        @"This is the fourth line",
                        @"This is the fifth line",
                        nil];

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.tweetsArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *tweet = [self.tweetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"Via Cuong Doan"];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:tweet];

    return cell;
}    
@end
```

**AppDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    viewController *view = [[viewController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:view.view];
    return YES;
}
```

Everything seem fine, but `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` and `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` never get called

Comment: is ViewDidLoad gets called? I believe not

Comment: `viewDidLoad` gets called, but the other two are not, that's why it makes me confuse

Comment: `numberOfSecion` not set?

Comment: it is such an ugly implementation of the `–application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method... :/

Comment: Sorry, numberOfSection is 1 by default. Maybe a `reloadData`.

Comment: Well, I don't mind getting a downvote, but at least please let me know why

Comment: Have you confirmed by logging that those methods are not called? Do you ever create the window in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: @rdelmar thank you very much, I forgot to init `window`, how clumsy am I

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use [self.window addSubview:view.view], but instead, use self.window.rootViewController = view;

Comment: @rdelmar I see, thank you very much, please make it an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the window in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and also you shouldn't manually add the controller's view to the window, you should make the controller the window's root view controller,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = view;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

in your first line?

Comment: This would only fix a compiler warning and would have no effect at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: This won't help - the methods in question are part of the dataSource, not the delegate.